# SideWaffle template does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sidewaffle

I want to create my own empty controller template using `SideWaffle` as described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/12/26/how-to-customize-the-generated-files-from-the-new-scaffolded-item-dialog.aspx). The process is simple: I just change template code `Controller.cs.t4` inside 'CodeTemplates/MvcControllerEmpty' to test my template. I followed documention and I just move "using namespace" to class definition. But when I add new `Empty Controller` to web project, it does not create my template. Currently my Templates is as follow:

```
<#@ template language="C#" HostSpecific="True" #>
<#@ output extension="cs" #>
<#@ parameter type="System.String" name="ControllerName" #>
<#@ parameter type="System.String" name="ControllerRootName" #>
<#@ parameter type="System.String" name="Namespace" #>
<#@ parameter type="System.String" name="AreaName" #>

namespace <#= Namespace #>
{
    public class <#= ControllerName #> : Controller
    {
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Web;
        using System.Web.Mvc;
        //
        // GET: <#= (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(AreaName)) ? ("/" + AreaName) : String.Empty    #>/<#= ControllerRootName #>/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
             return View();
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: There are two types of empty controllers; Empty MVC Controller and Empty Web API. Are you sure you invoked the scaffolder that you customized? I did the exact same thing when I was trying it out. I think its because in the folders the Web API ones are listed first (since the folder names start with API) and in the UI the MVC ones are listed first. Perhaps you are running into the same thing?

Comment: I am quite sure that I change just mvc empty controller. but what you mean "are you sure you invoked the scaffolder that you customized."? I add controller by right click on "controllers" folder, select add new controller and in box appears I select "Empty Mvc Controller".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

I download  [ASP.NET and Web Tools 2013.1 for Visual Studio 2012](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=390062) (Because currently I am use visual studio 2012) and install that using web platform installer. And then installed [SideWaffle](http://sidewaffle.com/). After that I tried again and it works fine!